# run search query inside another query with only the id

Tags: mysql

i've tried to solve one query to search all the parameters in datatables script with serverside .. but in one of the fields of table A, i call the id of table B. i need to search for the description of table B, i've tried this.

```
select * from asesor
where dni_asesor like '%"der"%' or 
apellido_paterno like '%"SOMETHING"%' or 
apellido_materno like '%"SOMETHING"%' or 
nombres like '%"SOMETHING"%' or nro_cuenta like '%"SOMETHING"%' or 
(select distinct cliente.nombre_cliente FROM cliente join asesor on cliente.id_cliente=asesor.id_cliente where nombre_cliente like '%"SOMETHING"%')
```

the tables are:

```
Table: asesor
Columns:
id_asesor int(11) UN zerofill AI PK 
dni_asesor varchar(50) 
apellido_paterno varchar(50) 
apellido_materno varchar(50) 
nombres varchar(50) 
id_cliente int(11) 


Table: cliente
Columns:
id_cliente int(11) UN zerofill AI PK 
dni_cliente varchar(50) 
nombre_cliente varchar(50)
```

please help!!! :D

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: Consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements, AND a desired result

Comment: Table: asesor
Columns:
id_asesor int(11) UN zerofill AI PK 
dni_asesor varchar(50) 
apellido_paterno varchar(50) 
apellido_materno varchar(50) 
nombres varchar(50) 
id_cliente int(11) 


Table: cliente
Columns:
id_cliente int(11) UN zerofill AI PK 
dni_cliente varchar(50) 
nombre_cliente varchar(50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a check on the other table by using a left join from `asesor` to `cliente`. Then if there's a match on the `id_cliente` between the two tables, `nombre_cliente` will not be null and you can test the value of it. If there is no match, then `nombre_cliente` will be null, and it will fail the condition in your `where` clause.

I haven't tested this because I don't have your tables, but it should work for you.

```
SELECT * FROM asesor
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT cliente.nombre_cliente, id_cliente FROM cliente) cliente
  ON cliente.id_cliente=asesor.id_cliente
WHERE dni_asesor LIKE '%"der"%' OR 
apellido_paterno LIKE '%"SOMETHING"%' OR 
apellido_materno LIKE '%"SOMETHING"%' OR 
nombres LIKE '%"SOMETHING"%' OR nro_cuenta LIKE '%"SOMETHING"%' OR
cliente.nombre_cliente LIKE '%"SOMETHING"%'
```

Comment: the tables are...

Table: asesor
Columns:
id_asesor int(11) UN zerofill AI PK 
dni_asesor varchar(50) 
apellido_paterno varchar(50) 
apellido_materno varchar(50) 
nombres varchar(50) 
id_cliente int(11) 


Table: cliente
Columns:
id_cliente int(11) UN zerofill AI PK 
dni_cliente varchar(50) 
nombre_cliente varchar(50)

Comment: @ezzeonursito Have you tested my query?